# How can I get the latest bar of a date time in TradingView?

Tags: pine-script

I wanna find the specific time e.g.: 15:00 in the latest bars, not including other 15:00 bars of other days.

I know how to find a specific time in all period:

```
open_hour = 15
open_minute = 0
start_bar = (minute(time) == open_minute) and (hour(time) == open_hour)
```

But, I don't want to include other bars over the history. What I want is to pick the latest bar with that time.

Comment: Haven't used pine-script but the documentation looks pretty handy. Perhaps you can add to your start_bar variable to include dayoftheweek == dayoftheweek(t) and weekofyear == weekofyear(t) - or something along those lines?   https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html?#built-in-variables-for-working-with-time

Comment: if so, it will be still cycled in whole period, unless I specify a certain year, month and day.

Answer (score 0):

The script below will cycle back until the first 15:00 candle (in exchange timezone) will be met and plot the label above the bar (ignoring other 15:00 candles):

```
//@version=4
MAX_BARS_BACK = 4999
study("Last 15:00 candle", max_bars_back = MAX_BARS_BACK)

for i = 0 to MAX_BARS_BACK
    var label _label = na
    if hour[i] == 15 and minute[i] == 0
        label.delete(_label[1])
        _label := label.new(bar_index[i], high[i], '15:00', xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(#000000, 100), label.style_label_up, color.red)
        break
```

[image]

Load the script on the chart and hit the 'Replay' button.